# Problems inheriting XMLHttpRequest / ActiveXObject classes

Tags: javascript, oop, inheritance, xmlhttprequest, activexobject

I have the following JavaScript class:

```
var Server = function(onError)
{
    /* public As, onError; */

    var that, Key, Headers;

    this.__construct = function()
    {
        that = this;

        that.As = false;
        that.onError = onError;
        that.resetHeaders();

        onError = null;

        // Here I try to call the parent constructor (it seems I can't).

        if(window.XMLHttpRequest)
            that.XMLHttpRequest();
        else
            that.ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
    }

    this.Request = function(File, PostData, Function)
    {
        var Method, HeaderKey;

        if(PostData == null)
            Method = 'GET';
        else
            Method = 'POST';

        try
        {
            that.open(Method, File, that.As);

            /* Each request sets X-Requested-With to XMLHttpRequest by default.
               If PostData is given, then we treat it's content type as a form.*/

            that.setRequestHeader('X-Requested-With', 'XMLHttpRequest');

            if(PostData != null)
                that.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');

            for(HeaderKey = 0; HeaderKey < Headers.length; HeaderKey++)
                that.setRequestHeader(Headers[ HeaderKey ].Name, Headers[ HeaderKey ].Value);

            if(Function != null)
                that.onreadystatechange = function()
                {
                    if(that.readyState == 4 && that.status == 200)
                        Function.call();
                }

            that.send(PostData);
        }
        catch(Exception)
        {
            if(that.onError != null)
                that.onError(Exception);
        }
    }

    this.addHeader = function(Name, Value)
    {
        Headers[ Key ] = {};
        Headers[ Key ].Name = Name;
        Headers[ Key ].Value = Value;

        Key++;
    }

    this.resetHeaders = function()
    {
        Headers = [];
        Key = 0;
    }

    this.__construct();
}

if(window.XMLHttpRequest)
    Server.prototype = new XMLHttpRequest();
else
    Server.prototype = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');

Server.prototype.constructor = Server;
```

Where I make an inheritance depending on the state of the window.XMLHttpRequest var. In the __construct method I re-check this again for call the parent constructor.

I don't know if this is the correct form, but I would like that anyone could tell me what's wrong in here. By the way, when I check the console in Chrome I get the following exception: *"Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'XMLHttpRequest'"*, so I assume that it is not identifying the correct reference, however, I can see that all the properties / methods are present when I put the "." in the console, but I can't get access from a internal / external way (this is commenting the parent constructor  condition). Thank you, I'll wait for your replies.

Comment: `if(window.XMLHttpRequest) that.XMLHttpRequest();` That's the type error. You're trying to invoke the method `XMLHttpRequest` on the object. I think thats just a mistake

Comment: I'm a bit confused about this, when I make the inheritance I set the Server class as the constructor, so I though it would require to call the parent constructor in order to manipulate the class reference.

Comment: Then, how can I invoke the parent properties / methods from inside the class?